# "Remote control links" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Imagine viewing a web page @ mysite2/world and opening up a JavaScript popup at mysite/includes/popups.php. The popup features the following link:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="opener.location='http://www.mysite2.com/world/canada'">Canada</a>
```

When you click the link in the popup, the MAIN PAGE (mysite2/world) forwards to mysite2/world/canada. The popup just hangs there, waiting for you to click similar links.

It all worked when the links to the popup looked like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_openBrWindow('http://www.mysite.com/includes/popups.php?values=px|na','na','[insert popup attributes here]')">popup</a>
```

However, I found a new script that does away with the onClick stuff. My links now look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/includes/popups.php?values=px|na" rel="popup standard 200 200">North America</a>
```

The popups open as they should, but when I click a link (to /world/canada, for example), instead of forwarding the main page to mysite2/world/canada, it forwards it to the the site's home page. So it's working in the sense that it forces the main page to a different URL - just not the URL I want it to go to.

Does anyone know how to modify my script to re-enable "remote-controlled" link forwarding? I obviously need to delete the reference to onclick, but I don't know what to replace it with.

P.S. Here's the code from my head section:

```
function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture){if(elm.addEventListener)  {elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);return true;}else if (elm.attachEvent){var r =   elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);return r;}else{elm['on' + evType] = fn;}}
        var newWindow = null;

        function closeWin(){
            if (newWindow != null){
                if(!newWindow.closed)
                    newWindow.close();
            }
        }

        function popUpWin(url, type, strWidth, strHeight){

            closeWin();

            type = type.toLowerCase();

            if (type == "fullscreen"){
                strWidth = screen.availWidth;
                strHeight = screen.availHeight;
            }
            var tools="";
            if (type == "standard") tools =     "resizable,toolbar=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,width="+strWidth+",height="+strHeight+",top=0,left=0";
            if (type == "console" || type == "fullscreen") tools =     "resizable,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,width="+strWidth+",height="+strHeight+",left=0,top=0";
            newWindow = window.open(url, "newWin", tools);
            newWindow.focus();
        }

        function doPopUp(e)
        {
        //set defaults - if nothing in rel attrib, these will be used
        var t = "standard";
        var w = "780";
        var h = "580";
        //look for parameters
        attribs = this.rel.split(" ");
        if (attribs[1]!=null) {t = attribs[1];}
        if (attribs[2]!=null) {w = attribs[2];}
        if (attribs[3]!=null) {h = attribs[3];}
        //call the popup script
        popUpWin(this.href,t,w,h);
        //cancel the default link action if pop-up activated
        if (window.event) 
            {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
            } 
        else if (e) 
            {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        function findPopUps()
        {
        var popups = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (i=0;i<popups.length;i++)
            {
            if (popups[i].rel.indexOf("popup")!=-1)
                {
                // attach popup behaviour
                popups[i].onclick = doPopUp;
                // add popup indicator
                if (popups[i].rel.indexOf("noicon")==-1)
                    {
                    popups[i].style.backgroundImage = "url(pop-up.gif)";
                    popups[i].style.backgroundPosition = "0 center";
                    popups[i].style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
                    popups[i].style.paddingLeft = "15px";
                    }
                // add info to title attribute to alert fact that it's a pop-up   window
                popups[i].title = popups[i].title + " [Opens in pop-up  window]";
                }
            }
        }

        addEvent(window, "load", findPopUps, false);
```

Comment: Can you whittle down your question somewhat? For example, we don't need to see the PHP in your anchor tag; it would help more to know exactly what the tag looks like when the browser gets it.

Comment: Done; I removed the PHP.

Comment: What is this 'new script' you found? It's not possible to debug the issue without knowing what code is handling the popups.

Comment: I got it @ http://accessify.com/features/tutorials/the-perfect-popup/ (I edited my original post, adding the script from my head section.)